# Recreating a TableLayout with savedInstanceState; appended rows all look the same

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am creating an Android app with a ViewPager/ActionBar Tab activity containing some Fragments. Each Fragment lets the user input a part of a diary entry.

What I'm trying to do is handle configuration changes such as screen rotation, by saving the form contents into the **savedInstanceState** bundle and fetching them back out again when the Fragment's view is recreated.

One of my fragments has a TableLayout with rows that can be added and removed dynamically. An 'Add' button causes a row to be inflated from XML and added to the TableLayout with **addView()**.

To illustrate, here's a screenshot of my interface (I can't post images inline yet!):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/edChq.png

The problem is that when I try to restore the table after a rotation for example, the last row is repeated throughout the table, even though the data being passed to **addEmotionRow()** from the HashMap is correct (different for each row):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zfkr.png

Here's how I save and restore the rows. To save I iterate through the table rows and put the data into a HashMap:

```
   @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        // Reference to table layout
        TableLayout emotionsTableLayout = (TableLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.emotionsTableLayout);

        // Fetch the emotions from the table and put them into the HashMap
        emotions = new HashMap<String, Float>();

        // Skip child at 0; it's the table header row
        for (int i = 1; i < emotionsTableLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
            // Get references to spinner and ratingbar
            TableRow currentTableRow = (TableRow) emotionsTableLayout.getChildAt(i);
            Spinner currentRowSpinner = (Spinner) currentTableRow.getChildAt(0);
            RatingBar currentRowRatingBar = (RatingBar) ((LinearLayout) currentTableRow.getChildAt(1)).getChildAt(0);

            // Store in HashMap
            emotions.put((String) currentRowSpinner.getSelectedItem(), currentRowRatingBar.getRating());
        }

        // Store the HashMap
        outState.putSerializable("emotions", emotions);
    }
```

To restore I do the reverse:

```
        // Restore any saved values
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            // Restore emotions HashMap
            emotions = (HashMap<String, Float>) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("emotions");

            // Restore emotions table
            for (Map.Entry<String, Float> entry : emotions.entrySet()) {
                // Add a new row
                addEmotionRow(rowInflater, rowContainer, emotionsTableLayout, entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            }

            // TODO: Restore negative feelings table

        } else {
            // Add initial emotion row
            addEmotionRow(rowInflater, rowContainer, emotionsTableLayout, null, null);

            // Add initial negative thought row
            addNegativeThoughtRow(rowInflater, rowContainer, negativeThoughtsTableLayout);
        }
```

Finally, here's my **addEmotionRow()** function:

```
private static void addEmotionRow(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, final TableLayout tableLayout, String emotion, Float intensity) {
    // Generate a new row from XML
    final TableRow newRow = (TableRow) inflater.inflate(R.layout.table_row_emotion, tableLayout, false);

    ImageButton removeEmotionButton = (ImageButton) newRow.findViewById(R.id.removeEmotionButton);

    removeEmotionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(newRow.getContext(), android.R.anim.fade_out);
            anim.setAnimationListener(new TableRowRemoveAnimationListener(tableLayout, newRow));
            newRow.startAnimation(anim);
        }
    });

    // Set the emotion if given
    if (emotion != null) {
        // String array of emotions
        String[] emotionsArray = container.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.emotions);

        // Convert emotions description to index
        int spinnerIndex = Arrays.asList(emotionsArray).indexOf(emotion);

        // Get reference to spinner
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) newRow.findViewById(R.id.emotionSpinner);

        // Set spinner
        spinner.setSelection(spinnerIndex);
    }

    // Set the intensity if given
    if (intensity != null) {
        // Get reference to rating bar
        RatingBar currentRowRatingBar = (RatingBar) newRow.findViewById(R.id.intensityRatingBar);

        // Set rating
        currentRowRatingBar.setRating(intensity);
    }

    // Show the table header if we are about to gain a row
    View emotionsTableHeader = tableLayout.findViewById(R.id.tableHeader);
    if (emotionsTableHeader.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
        Animation fadeInAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(emotionsTableHeader.getContext(), android.R.anim.fade_in);
        emotionsTableHeader.startAnimation(fadeInAnim);
        emotionsTableHeader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    tableLayout.addView(newRow);
}
```

Do I have a problem with threads and/or timing here?

Comment: Where do you do the data restore, in which method?

Comment: I do the data restore inside the Fragment's **onCreateView()** method. Is this the wrong place for doing such tasks? Thanks!

Comment: Try to do the restore in the `onActivityCreated()` callback. The system might do some restoring on its own after the views is built cancelling what you want to do.

Comment: Ok - moving the restore to onActivityCreated() didn't fix it, but it seems to make more sense putting it there, so thankyou for making me aware of it. What **did** fix it was putting the calls to **addEmotionRow()** into a **Runnable** and posting it with the TableLayout View's handler. Any ideas why that fixes it? I've also changed the HashMap to a LinkedHashMap so that order is preserved.

Comment: The `Runnable` will delay the code until the current message on the UI thread is processed. Running the code from `onActivityCreated()` should have resulted in the same output. The system restores the data on its own at some time and because the TableRows have the same ids(?) you end up with the data of the last row(so the `LinkedHashMap` or normal `Map` doesn't count).